# Yii Login not Working

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I'm new to Yii PHP Framework and I'm trying to work on a login form. I know there's already a login function on Yii when you install the testdrive app. I just edit it to make login via database and it's not working. I don't have any errors in codes but when I login it always says incorrect password or username. Here's my code.

For UserIdentity.php

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
 * are both 'demo'.
 * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
 * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
    private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($record===null)
          $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($record->password!==crypt($this->password,$record->password))
          $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
          $this->_id=$record->id;
          $this->setState('title', $record->title);
          $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
       return !$this->errorCode;
     }

    public function getId()
    {
    return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Here's for SiteController.php

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: How did you save the password in db? have you encrypted it?

Comment: No. Password is in plain text. I just did execute mysql insert commands. Have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if your password saved in db text plain dont use crypt

```
    class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
 * are both 'demo'.
 * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
 * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
    private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($record===null)
          $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($record->password!==$this->password) // changed
          $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
          $this->_id=$record->id;
          $this->setState('title', $record->title);
          $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
       return !$this->errorCode;
     }

    public function getId()
    {
    return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but i go an error. 

    Property "User.title" is not defined.

Comment: ok it means that the login query is running well, now i will edit my answer for title problem.

Comment: be sure that there is title column in your user table, else set public $title; to top of your User model class

Answer (score 0):

In your coding,  the line

```
    else if($record->password!==crypt($this->password,$record->password))
```

is comparing the password with string hashing (`crypt()` makes the string hash/encription).

if you save the password in db without encrypting, you can compare the both user input password and the password you have saved in db directly, no need to apply `crypt()`

```
            ($this->password!==$record->password)
            //$this->password - user input
            //$record->password - save password from db
```

Now change the code as

```
        public function authenticate()
        {
            $record = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $this->username));
            if ($record === null)
                $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            else if (trim($this->password)!== $record->password)
                $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            else
            {
                $this->_id = $record->id;
                $this->setState('title', $record->title);
                $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
            }
            return !$this->errorCode;
        }
```